# C# code not catching SEHExceptions

Tags: c#, visual-c++, c++-cli

I have a C# application that invokes a managed C++ DLL that deliberately accesses to an invalid address; I enabled `SEH Exceptions` in my C++ project, I added a `_se_translator_function` into my C++ code and I also added a signal handler when a `SIGSEGV` occurs. Using my C++ code from a purely native test, everything works perfectly, but when I invoke my C++ code from a .net app, the app crashes with a:

> Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to
>   read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other
>   memory is corrupt.

```
   at K.killnative() in c:\users\ebascon\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\consoleapplication3\consoleapplication4\source.cpp:line 32
```

This is my C# console app:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            try {
                var k = new NativeKiller();
                k.kill();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine("Catching " + ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the C++/CLI code invoked:

```
void MXXExceptionTranslator(unsigned int, struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS*)
{
    throw std::exception("Crash happens");
}

void killnative() {
    try {
        _set_se_translator(MXXExceptionTranslator);

        signal(SIGSEGV, [](int) {
            puts("Exception");
            exit(-1);
        });

        int* p = reinterpret_cast<int*>(0xDEADBEEF);
        printf("%d\n", *p);
    }
    catch (...) { //Removing this catch does not change anything
        puts("Doing nothing");
    }
}

public ref class NativeKiller {
public:
    void kill() {
        killnative();
    }
};
```

What do you think I am doing wrong? In my real world problem, I need this C++/CLI process (that is a bridge with a legacy app) to log an error message and die gracefully instead of popping the "The program stopped working" window.

Thanks in advance,

Ernesto

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the start of your application and run it. Then try the Debug -> Attach to Process menu. Under "Attach to", select Managed (the one relative to your C# project's .NET version), and Native. Also be sure to select Managed Compatability Mode. These 3 options will let you debug into your unmanaged DLL. Check to see exactly what line it fails on inside of your unmanaged C++ DLL and report back to us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the good kind of problem to have, it helps you discover that you are not building your code correctly.  The C++/CLI compiler is pretty powerful, almost *too* powerful, and can translate almost any native code into IL.  The exact same kind of IL that a C# compiler generates.  And it is treated the same at runtime, the jitter translates it to machine code at runtime.

This is not usually something you actually want.  Native C or C++ code ought to be translated directly to machine code by the compiler.  The MSDN article for _set_se_translator() does a decent job of warning about this:

> When using _set_se_translator from managed code (code compiled with /clr) or mixed native and managed code, be aware that the translator affects exceptions generated in native code only. Any managed exceptions generated in managed code (such as when raising System::Exception) are not routed through the translator function.

The usual way to fall in the pit of success is by compiling the native code separately in its own source file or library project.  But even easier is to take advantage of the C++/CLI compiler's ability to dynamically switch back-and-forth between IL and machine code generation in a single source file.  Fix:

```
#pragma managed(push, off)
void MXXExceptionTranslator(unsigned int, struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS*) { ... }
void killnative() { ... }
#pragma managed(pop)

public ref class NativeKiller { ... }
```

And you'll now see that the exception translator works fine.

Comment: Thanks Hans, but your solution does not work :( the error window is still being shown. I will modify my tests in order to set this from a native project and invoking the a managed method from there and I will see what will happen.

Comment: what I did and worked for me is creating a c++ unmanaged project, setting the SEH translator function and invoking the C++/CLI stuff from there. I will try to implement your solution again. Thanks!!!

Comment: Hans: You were right. Your solution works perfectly! I set the pragmas in wrong places. Thanks! :)